# withContext - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

In Android app I want to execute network operation in background thread.
So I use Kotlin coroutines `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` for this:

snippet:

```
@GET("trader/{trader_operation}")
    Deferred<Response<Void>> executeTraderOperation(@Path("trader_operation") String traderOperation,
                                                    @Query("base") String base,
                                                    @Query("quote") String quote,
                                                    @Query("sender") String sender,


import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import retrofit2.Response
import java.util.*
class TransportService {
        companion object {
            private val SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_CODE = 503

            private val TAG = TransportService::class.java.name@Query("key") String key);

     suspend fun executeTraderOperation(traderOperation: Trader.Operation, base: String, quote: String): NetworkResponse {
                val traderMonitorRestClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient(TraderMonitorRestClient::class.java)
                val sender = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "_" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
                val key = DateUtil.getDateAsString(Date(), "mmHHddMMyyyy")
                val operrationDeferred: Deferred<Response<Void>> = traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base.trim(), quote.trim(), sender, key)
                return executeOperation(operrationDeferred)
            }

            private suspend fun executeOperation(operation: Deferred<Response<*>>): NetworkResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val networkResponse = NetworkResponse()
                try {
                    val response = operation.await()
                    networkResponse.isSuccess = response.isSuccessful
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        networkResponse.successResponse = response
                    } else {
                        val errorResponse = ErrorUtils.parseError(response)
                        networkResponse.errorResponse = errorResponse
                    }
                    networkResponse
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    val errorResponse = ErrorResponse()
                    errorResponse.setCode(SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_CODE)
                    errorResponse.setMessage("Service unavailable")
                    networkResponse.errorResponse = errorResponse
                    networkResponse
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

But I get runtime error in this line:

```
val operrationDeferred: Deferred<Response<Void>> = traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base.trim(), quote.trim(), sender, key)
```

here error:

```
06-14 15:23:45.394 9534-9534/? W/top: type=1400 audit(0.0:39232676): avc: denied { search } for name="7" dev="proc" ino=9011 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0



 Throwing new exception 'length=117; index=1902' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=117; index=1902
   at java.lang.Object com.myptoject.service.TransportService$Companion.executeTraderOperation2(com.myptoject.model.Trader$Operation, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, kotlin.coroutines.Continuation) (TransportService.kt:37)
   at java.lang.Object com.myptoject.viewmodel.TradersViewModel$doClickExecuteTraderOperation$1.invokeSuspend(java.lang.Object) (TradersViewModel.kt:60)
   at void kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(java.lang.Object) (ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
   at void kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run() (Dispatched.kt:238)
   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:739)
   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:95)
   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:148)
   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Check your response by inspecting your network traffic. You're getting an ArrayOutOfBounds exception, meaning something tried to access an element in an array that is beyond the boundaries of said array; the code you published, doesn't contain this information, so it's going to be your job to debug and print the HTTP response and evaluate why your model is not working when you parse the response.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini the problem was gone if I use this signature for method: suspend fun executeTraderOperation(traderOperation: Trader.Operation, base: String, quote: String): NetworkResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {...